# Nexus 3.6 OSS Docker Hub Proxy - Can docker search but not docker pull

Tags: proxy, nexus, dockerhub, sonatype, nexus3

I've deployed Nexus OSS 3.6 and it's being served on http://server:8082/nexus

I have configured a docker-hub proxy using the instructions in http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2017/02/16/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-3-docker-images/ and have configured the docker-group to serve under port 18000

I can perform the following:

```
docker login server:18000
docker search server:18000/jenkins
```

but when I run:

```
docker pull server:18000/jenkins
```

i get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get http://10.105.139.17:18000/v2/jenkins/manifests/latest: 
error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid character '<' 
looking for beginning of value: 
"<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" 
content=\"text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1\"/>\n<title>
Error 400 </title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2>HTTP ERROR: 400</h2>\n
<p>Problem accessing /nexus/v2/token. 
Reason:\n<pre>    Not a Docker request</pre></p>\n<hr />
<a href=\"http://eclipse.org/jetty\">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.20.v20170531</a><hr/>\n
</body>\n</html>\n"
```

My jetty nexus.properties config file is:

```
# Jetty section
application-port=8082
application-host=0.0.0.0
# nexus-args=${jetty.etc}/jetty.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-http.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-requestlog.xml
nexus-context-path=/nexus

# Nexus section
# nexus-edition=nexus-pro-edition
# nexus-features=\
#  nexus-pro-feature
```

Could anyone offer any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Comment: What version of Docker is being used? Version 1.8 is the minimum supported version.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when I enabled the anonymous read on some docker repository.

Repositories->Docker hosted->Check the checkbox (Disable to allow anonymous pull) from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

seems you need to upgrade Nexus to 3.6.1 according to : 
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14488
in order to allow  anonymous read again